# How to use existing Database

Tags: linux, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have successfully installed oracle 12c release 2 on centos7 also i am able to access my database using sqlplus command.

My questions are:

1. How to create new database ?
2. How to use existing data which i had created during installations time ? we are trying to access created databases using command [use databases_name;] as used in sql but we are to able to access the databases in oracle.
3. Is it possible to access database in GUI ?

Please provide some adequate solution that will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Oracle doesn't work like MySQL (or SQL Server, or PostgreSQL, or...). Make sure you're familiar with the basics (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/title.htm is a good start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect as a privileged user (such as SYS) and check which users you already have by running

```
SQL> select username, account_status
  2  from dba_users
  3  order by username;

USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS
------------------------------ -------------------------
ANONYMOUS                      OPEN
APEX_PUBLIC_USER               LOCKED
APEX_040000                    LOCKED
<snip>
HR                             LOCKED    --> this one
<snip>
SCOTT                          OPEN
SYS                            OPEN
SYSTEM                         OPEN
<snip>    
17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

One of pre-installed users is HR (human resources); it contains several tables you might want to use. If it is locked (and if you don't know its password), do the following:

```
SQL> alter user hr account unlock;

User altered.

SQL> alter user hr identified by hr;

User altered.

SQL>
```

Now you can connect as HR and practice your SQL skills:

```
SQL> connect hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> select table_name from user_tables;

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
REGIONS
LOCATIONS
DEPARTMENTS
JOBS
EMPLOYEES
JOB_HISTORY
PRODUCT_INFORMATION
MYTABLE
DEPT
COUNTRIES

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

As of your question about "creating a database": I presume you meant "user", not "database". Unless you are a DBA, you will not be creating any of those. Though, creating users is somewhat similar (I mean, DBAs do that, not developers). Anyway: still connected as SYS, you'd

- check which tablespaces you have
- create user
- grant it some privileges

Here's how:

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user sushant identified by kunwar
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to sushant;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now, connect as newly created user and *do something*:

```
SQL> connect sushant/kunwar
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
       100

SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

If it turns out that you need additional privileges, you know how to grant them.

---

GUI you're looking for is SQL Developer, a free tool available for download on Oracle Technology Network.

---

Shortly, that would be it. For much more info, I'd suggest you read documentation. Start with the Concepts book, have a look at 2-day DBA, then move on to SQL, PL/SQL etc. Good luck!

Comment: Hello
Thank you for your valuable reply now i am able to connect database also i have created tables successfully. Really it 's a very helpful.

Thanks a lot.